# Round up to the nearest .5 decimal in swift

Tags: swift

I have a function that looks like this

```
bits = bits * 1.5
```

So if bits was 1 it would return 1.5 but if the function was run again it would return 2.25 however i would prefer if it were to just round up to 2.5 is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try the following function from [globalnerdy.com](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/01/26/better-to-be-roughly-right-than-precisely-wrong-rounding-numbers-with-swift/):

In your case you could use `bits = roundUp(bits, 0.5)` after the multiplication by 1.5.

```
func roundUp(_ value: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
  return ceil(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by doing...

```
round(x * 3) * 0.5
```

So multiply by 3. Then round it to the nearest int. Then divide by 2.

So you have still multiplied by 1.5 but it gets rounded to the nearest 0.5

1.5 * 3 = 4.5

Rounded = 5

5 / 2 = 2.5

Which is what you wanted

Edit: if you want to always go up to the nearest 0.5 then use `ceiling` instead of `round`.